# Neo4j connectivity with jaspersoft

Tags: neo4j

1. I want to connect Neo4j to Jaspersoft studio. I dnt find a already available driver for Neo4j in jaspersoft. Can anyone pls provide me the procedural steps for connecting it to jaspersoft studio. I have the jaspersoft Neo4j connector with me.
2. I have created an index.
   Eg: Create index on :cl(cname) and index is created successfully.
   Now I have run a sample query like

MATCH (c:cl { clname:'Service' })-[r]->(dom)
RETURN r

But it is displaying 0 relationships even if I have relationships associated with those nodes.
Can anyone pls help me out in the schema indexing and quering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the source link for the connector? 
I thin it was created a long time ago and should be upgraded to 2.x and cypher.

How do you execute the cypher queries?

You have a typo, cname vs clname in the two queries